# Attempt to present * on * which is already presenting (null)

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am using the following code to present alert controller,but sometimes it gices the above message and the alert controller  stops responding.What does it mean and how it can be fixed?

```
+(void)showAlertFor:(UIViewController *)viewController Title:(NSString*)title WithMessage:(NSString *)message
{

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:message   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; //Getting the alert view controller
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];

    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [viewController  presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: check you are presenting more than one controller.

Comment: How this can be done?

Comment: @TestShroff have you calling `showAlertFor` from two locations on the same? or while dismiss VC?

Comment: yes I am calling it on the same view controller....once in the view did load and other on the click of a button on viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
+(void)showAlertFor:(UIViewController *)viewController withTitle:(NSString*)title withMessage:(NSString *)message {

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:message   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; //Getting the alert view controller
    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];

    [alertController addAction:ok];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [viewController  presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Calling it on main thread will solve your problem. And make sure you are not presenting any other controller at same time.

Comment: It now gives the following warning and still causes problem"Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior".How this can be fixed?